# Noun for someone who respects no authority, recognizes no national boundaries, no political parties?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that can sum up the entire nature of someone who does not respect authority, recognizes no boundaries, and recognizes no political establishment.

Comment: It wouldn't be their *entire* nature, but you might be looking for the term [*anarchist*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anarchy).

Comment: This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the word [anarchist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anarchist).

An anarchist is someone who believes in and/or promotes [anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism):

> Anarchism is a political philosophy that advocates self-governed societies based on voluntary institutions. [...] Anarchism holds the state to be undesirable, unnecessary, and harmful.
>   *(wikipedia)*

It comes from [anarchy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=anarchy):

> from Greek anarkhia "lack of a leader, the state of people without a government"
>   *(etymonline)*

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to **anarchist** (and I think closer to what the OP is asking) would be **nihilist** -- one who espouses the concepts of nihilism.

The primary definition of "nihilist" in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nihilist?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) reads as follows:

> 1.a :  a viewpoint that traditional values and beliefs are  unfounded and that existence is senseless and useless.

Partly, it's a matter of degree -- while often conflated (especially in the nineteenth century) nihilists were characteristically more extreme than anarchists, and would reject social and moral structures entirely.  Anarchists, in contrast, were in favor of replacing current (hierarchical) social structures with more communal ones.

Robert Louis Stevenson, in [More New Arabian Nights: The Dynamiter](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/647) (1885), has a rather lighthearted take on the matter as it played out in nineteenth century London.

Comment: It's all a matter of perception, but I would personally deem the anarchists more violent, at least in the 20th century. But then I am looking at, for example, Greece, with a long anarchist tradition and even anarchist terrorists. Nihilism, on the other hand, I usually associate with Camus, as a darker, fatalistic implementation of existentialism (and, yes, the basis of the punk movement - although some punks associated with anarchy again...) The two are definitely linked and intertwined.

Comment: "anarchia", in Classical Greek, was a (pejorative) term referring to a specific mode of non-hierarchical government, or total absence of government, and is found in English as early as the late sixteenth century.  "nihilism", in contrast, first appears in English in the early nineteenth century.  Both terms shift in precise meaning and reference depending on time and context, obviously.  But I don't think Bakunin would ever have seen himself as a nihilist. I wouldn't see Camus idea of the Absurd as quite comparable to nihilism -- maybe something like "extreme skepticism"?

Comment: Along with the Stevenson novel I mentioned above, two by Joseph Conrad are relevant here -- _The Secret Agent_ and _Under Western Eyes_.  And of course above all, Dostoievsky's _The Devils_ (sometimes, _The Possessed_).